# Understanding hockeyapp Crash report Stacktrace

Tags: c#, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I have an UWP app with c# that has linked In HockeyApp, I receive the crash report with a stack trace elements like this:

```
MyNS.Controls.CheckInControlVM.<>c.<AddHuespedSlot>b__63_0(SearchPeopleListItem) + 0x4
```

Is not clear form me what means:

```
b__63_0
```

or

```
+ 0x4
```

What is the proper interpretation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload the symbol files(which is pdb file in UWP) to HockeyApp so that the crash report become readable, refer their kb on how to upload symbols for UWP application(https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application#4-verify-build-id-of-symbols)

Sometimes the pdb files you uploaded doesn't match the binary so these crash report couldn't be symbolicated correctly, in this case you could verify their correspondence by comparing the Bundle ID: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application#4-verify-build-id-of-symbols

Comment: Tks I'm going to take a look to it.